# calculate parallel trajectory on a GIS map

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have some way points with longitudes and latitudes which builds a trajectory and I want to calculate a parallel trajectory at a specific distance!

I would appreciate any help!

Best regards,

Tara

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dijkstra's algorithm.

More explanation here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: How could the Dijkstra's algorithm help me? I just have the way points !

Answer (score 0):

If you want that both the trajectory and the parallel trajectory will be composed of geodesics - you can't.

The path between two points is usually defined by a [geodesic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic). Geodesic is a generalization of the notion of a straight line, or a straight line segment to curved spaces. Geodesic is the shortest route between two points on the Earth's surface, namely, a segment of a [great circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle).

Great circles divide the sphere in two equal hemispheres and all great circles intersect each other. Therefore, there are no parallel geodesics.